# Exception in querying mongodb using spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to query MongoDB with the following code. Though as per documentation it seems correct I am still getting runtime exception at the time of execution of the query. Please let me know if there is anything wrong.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {    
@Query("{'mobileNumber': ?0, 'password': ?1 }")
    User findByLogin(String mobileNumber, String password);

}
```

Exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting ':' but found 'password'.] with root cause

org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting ':' but found 'password'.
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:132) ~[bson-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:149) ~[bson-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.decode(DocumentCodec.java:45) ~[bson-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:105) ~[bson-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.bson.Document.parse(Document.java:90) ~[bson-3.6.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery.<init>(BasicQuery.java:67) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.createQuery(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(Abstra
```